# How to host an mp3 player that accepts mp3 file as GET request

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'd like to put an mp3 player on my SiteGround hosted site that will allow me to play files by passing a third party mp3 url as a parameter.  I need Play/Pause/Timeline/Volume controls.

So I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
<?php
   if( $_GET["thefile"]) { 
      echo '<audio controls>';
      echo '<source src="'. $_GET["thefile"]. '" type="audio/mpeg">';
      echo '</audio>';
      exit();
   } 
?> 

<html> 
   <body> 

      <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET"> 
         Enter MP3 URL: <input type = "text" name = "thefile" /> 
         <input type = "submit" /> 
      </form> 

   </body> 
</html>
```

The page loads with the player but doesn't play.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I'm not looking for free code so much as suggested 'solutions.'  Stackoverflow only  gives a couple of potentially relevant categories and I saw this as more related to coding than the other options.  Do you have a suggestion of a more suitable way or method to request assistance?  It's not that I haven't searched for an answer myself here and elsewhere. @DerekPollard

Comment: this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, I'm sure, but this is working for my purposes:

```
<?php
   if( $_GET["thefile"]) {
      $encoded_url = urldecode($_GET["thefile"]);
      echo '<audio controls src="'. $encoded_url. '"></audio>';
      exit();
   } 
?> 
<html> 
   <body> 

      <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET"> 
         Enter MP3 URL: <input type = "text" name = "thefile" /> 
         <input type = "submit" /> 
      </form> 

   </body> 
</html>
```